# Overriding Ctrl+Z behavior in matlab zoom mode

Tags: matlab, user-interface, callback, matlab-guide

I want my own <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> handler called while in zoom mode rather than the default handler. I found [this article](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/enabling-user-callbacks-during-zoom-pan#more-6043) on Undocumented Matlab and tried this:

```
function zoomIn_OnCallback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
  set(handles.image_handle, 'ButtonDownFcn', []);
  zoom on;
  [handles.mode_manager.WindowListenerHandles.Enabled] = deal(false);
  handles.theGui.WindowKeyPressFcn =  [];
  handles.theGui.KeyPressFcn = @theGui_KeyPressFcn;
end
```

The code executes, but doesn't override the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> behavior of zoom mode.

I thought I exactly followed the example code from Undocumented Matlab, but obviously something isn't right.

Comment: Firstly, I changed your [guide] tag to [matlab-guide]; please read the tag wiki info for tags you want to use for your question. Secondly, undocumented features always come with the caveat that they can break any time with respect to versions. Are you sure you're using a version of MATLAB that should support the corresponding undocumented features?

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the caveat. A perfectly useful answer would be that this doesn't work anymore. I'm using Matlab R2016a (9.0.0.341360), which is newer than the version at the time of the Undocumented Matlab post. There are no updates to the post to indicate that it has stopped working and a sample code posted by a commenter still works.