# Listening for key press in MATLAB zoom mode

Tags: matlab, user-interface, keypress

I want to be able to use WindowKeyPressFcn when a figure is in zoom mode. This question has been asked recently here [Overriding ctrl-z behavior in matlab zoom mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987567/overriding-ctrl-z-behavior-in-matlab-zoom-mode), but I have just made a minimal example to demonstrate the same problem (I would have written a comment on their post, but don't have enough rep yet). Does anyone know what we are missing?

```
function listenWhileZooming

%% Main problem:
% I want any key press to change the color of the plot, even when in Zoom
% mode. I tried to override the mode manager, but don't see any effect.
%%

%% Create and then hide the GUI as it is being constructed
f = figure('Visible','off','units','normalized','Position',[0.1 0.1 0.5 0.5],'windowkeypressfcn',@colorSwap);

%% Override mode manager
hManager = uigetmodemanager(f);
try
    set(hManager.WindowListenerHandles, 'Enable', 'off');  % HG1
catch
    [hManager.WindowListenerHandles.Enabled] = deal(false);  % HG2
end
set(f, 'WindowKeyPressFcn',@colorSwap);

%% Plot something
plot(1,1,'bo')

%% Make the GUI visible
f.Visible = 'on';

%% Key press callback
    function colorSwap(source,eventData)
        myLine = findobj(source,'type','line');
        if all(myLine.Color == [0 0 1])
            plot(1,1,'ro')
        else
            plot(1,1,'bo')
        end
    end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late, but this is your missing piece.

I assume (as in your code) that `f` is the figure handle and `f.WindowKeyPressFcn` has been set by you.

```
%% Fix
Button = findall(f, 'Tag', 'Exploration.ZoomIn');
OldClickedCallback = Button.ClickedCallback;
Button.ClickedCallback = @(h, e) FixButton(f, OldClickedCallback, f.WindowKeyPressFcn);

Button = findall(f, 'Tag', 'Exploration.ZoomOut');
OldClickedCallback = Button.ClickedCallback;
Button.ClickedCallback = @(h, e) FixButton(f, OldClickedCallback, f.WindowKeyPressFcn);

function Result = FixButton(Figure, OldCallback, NewCallback)
    eval(OldCallback);
    hManager = uigetmodemanager(Figure); % HG 2 version
    [hManager.WindowListenerHandles.Enabled] = deal(false);
    Figure.KeyPressFcn = [];
    Figure.WindowKeyPressFcn = NewCallback;
    Result = true;
end
```

After `f.WindowKeyPressFcn` it set by you, it is reset by the zoom handler. So we highjack both zoom buttons (you can do the same with `Pan` or `Rotate`) to first call the original callback and then re-apply your fix. Also, don't forget to delete the `KeyPressFcn`. It's pretty elegant as you can use the same `FixButton` for all buttons.